# Convert JSON to CSV using Azure Databricks

Tags: python, database, azure, apache-spark, databricks

I'm new to Azure Databricks so I am having a hard time importing JSON data and converting it to CSV using Azure Databricks even after reading the documentation.

After converting JSON to CSV, I need to combine it with another CSV data that has a mutual column.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to join on the mutual column?  If so you can do something like this:

```
dfjson = spark.read.json(/path/to/json)
dfcsv = spark.read.csv(/path/to/csv)
dfCombined = dfjson.join(dfcsv, dfjson.mutualCol == dfcsv.mutualCol, joinType)

dfCombined.save.format(someFormat).write(/path/to/output)
```